# Facebook Graph API - Whitelisting

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, whitelist

QUESTION EDITED TO BE MORE SPECIFIC:

When attempting to read 'views' field for a user's public videos using the Graph API:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/facebook/videos?access_token=<token>&fields=views`

Using my application's access token, I receive the following error message:

`(#3) App must be on whitelist`

However, making the same request using the facebook Graph Explorer (with a Graph Explorer access token) the data is returned correctly.

Does anyone know how to request for an application to be adding to the said whitelist?When trying to extract data from the Facebook Graph API I get the message: "**(#3) App must be on whitelist**"

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your facebook app's setting>advanced setting and in 'Server IP Whitelist' field. mention the IP from which you are making request to Graph API